# How atomic are lockfiles in PHP?

Tags: php, locking, race-condition

I have a PHP page that should be accessible only by one user at a time. It's a kind of "poor man's cron": A "Javascript" file, that is requested in the background. At the moment I'm thinking of creating a lock file like this:

```
if(file_exists($lockfile) && filemtime($lockfile) + EXPIRES_AFTER > time() ) {
    die("// Page is locked.");
}

touch($lockfile);
// do stuff
unlink($lockfile);
echo "// Cron stuff was run";
```

But I'm not sure if there could be a very short window of opportunity between the `file_exists` and the `touch` call where another page request could check for the file existence and see that it isn't there. We're probably talking microseconds here so I would like top know at which amount of requests I really need to start worrying.

Comment: i don't think there is any chance of two requests conflict at the same exact time, and if that happens sometime in the lifetime of your application,.. try using a small queue and randomly select someone in queue to be serve the file. other than that i believe there is no answer in this question..

Comment: @GeoPhoenix: Why don't you think there's a chance? And how could he randomly select someone without creating the same race. (Race with someone joining the queue versus creating a new queue.)

Comment: The window of exposure is more a function of the system load than straightforwardly deducible from the number of requests.  20 heavy requests could bring up the load more than 1,000 trivial requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do this *really* precisely, then use a different approach, because there IS some time between the check and the lock.

Two possible implementations:

1. Use flock:
   https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php
2. Use something like STM:
   E.g. open the lockfile for append, write something into it, close the handle. Then read the file back, and if it only has what you wrote into it then you have acquired the lock.

Other than that, your original code would probably not cause any problems.

Answer (score 3):

There is no atomicity in the code you wrote, so yes, there is a race condition.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a race condition. Instead, [dio_open](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dio-open.php) the file with O_EXCL. This will fail if the file already exists. Unlink it when you're done.

The only thing to watch out for is if the system or the script crashes while the file exists, the script will never run again. If you are worried about this, check the age of the file (if you fail to create it) and if it's older than the longest the script could ever take, unlink it.

Using [flock](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) is another option.